# Why is Wien's Approximation accurate for wavelengths 0 to Max?

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

I'm currently reading "Robert Eisberg, Robert Resnick - Quantum Physics of Atoms, Molecules, Solids, Nuclei, and Particles", specifically Problem 23 in Chapter 1. The problem is shown below.

[image]

My question is simply why does $\frac{hc}{\lambda_{max}kT} = 4.965$ indicate Wien's approximation is fairly accurate in this region?

Comment: My general assumption is that, disregarding the constants in both Wien and Planks equations for energy density, this value produces a very similar value for the exponential parts, and as \lambda -> 0, the exponentials drop of at similar rates as the grow very big in the denominator so the -1 term in Planck's equation doesn't matter much. Is this all there is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Planck's Law, the energy density of blackbody radiation is proportional to
$$
u \propto \frac{1}{\lambda^5} \frac{1}{e^{hc/\lambda k T} - 1}
$$
If $e^{hc/\lambda k T} \gg 1$, we can neglect the $-1$ in the denominator ($e^{hc/\lambda k T} - 1 \approx e^{hc/\lambda k T}$) and we recover Wien's approximation.

Comment: I originally made a mistake and had a minus sign in the exp in Planck's Law, but thank you.